# Will imagedestroy() delete from disc

Tags: php, image, compression, gd

```
function png2jpg($originalFile, $outputFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
    imagejpeg($image, $outputFile.'.jpg', $quality);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

I'm using this for my image compression, but i keep finding my file I save deleted. Does imagedestroy() cause this to save memory or will it also delete the output file.

Comment: No, imagedestroy() removes the image resource from memory, an image resource may not even exist on disk - it isn't this that's deleting your image file from disk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No just in memory.

From the manual

> imagedestroy() frees any memory associated with image image.

Use [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete a file

Comment: My files are getting randomly deleted is what my problem is. That's why I asked if that'd delete it.

Comment: @jake i guess this is not the function deleting your images